# Folder did not break the 5k List View Threshold

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view-threshold

I have a document library with ~20k Folders.

SharePoint Online is telling me, that the list threshold is reached even if I navigate into a folder which only 4 documents in it.

But [Manage large lists and libraries in SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-sharepoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59) Support Site tells, that we can use folders to organize the documents:

> **Using folders to organize**    You can use folders to organize data
>   effectively, though you should be careful not to have a query on the
>   folder return more than the List View Threshold. For more info, see
>   Create a folder in a list or Create a folder in a document library.

Comment: How many folders you have in root folder of the library? folders face the same limitations as items so if you have more than 5k you may be facing issue.

Comment: approx 20k Folders in root... but if I navigate to a subfolder, the limitations should be "resettet"? Im okay with the fact, that I cant view the root folder without filters...

Comment: I don't think so I I remember correctly when you go above 5k limit on the root you are hitting this issue regardless of what folder you will navigate to in that hierarchy.

Comment: After removing the second sort attribute it seems to work...?!

Comment: ok you haven't mentioned sorting, if you use it ensure you have index on the column you use to sort. You can create it via the Library settings page.

Comment: I already did indexed all needed columns... its realy a strange behavior...